# Loop to compare number from list to field number in XML and print the attribute name

Tags: python, xml, for-loop

I have a list of numbers, e.g. [1,4,5,6] and I want to iterate over an xml file like:

```xml
<fields>
    <field number="2" name="Two" type="STRING"/>
    <field number="6" name="Six" type="STRING"/>
    <field number="7" name="Eight" type="STRING"/>
</fields>
```

Based on number, I want to print the name value (e.g. Six) of the XML is the number exists in the field number, and if a number is not available in the XML, e.g 1, state that 1 is not in the XML file

Answer (score 1):

You could use [`xml.etree.ElementTree.parse`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.parse) to parse the XML file into a [`xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree) instance:

```py
from xml.etree.ElementTree import parse

tree = parse("test.xml")
root = tree.getroot()
```

Then you could create a lookup dictionary of `number: name` pairs from iterating the *child* nodes from the *root* node:

```py
fields = {int(child.attrib["number"]): child.attrib["name"] for child in root}
```

Which will result in this setup:

```py
{2: 'Two', 6: 'Six', 7: 'Eight'}
```

Then you can iterate the numbers list and print if the number exists in this dictionary or not:

```py
numbers = [1, 4, 5, 6]

for number in numbers:
    print(fields.get(number, f"{number} does not exist in XML"))
```

We can use [`dict.get()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) to set a default message if the number is not found.

**Output:**

```
1 does not exist in XML
4 does not exist in XML
5 does not exist in XML
Six
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply - I am able to get the setup {2: 'Two', 6: 'Six', 7: 'Eight'} etc, however I have a list of strings for the names -  strings = [Eight, Six, Five] , how can I compare this list to the field setup, and state whether the strings in this list are in the fields. For example, print "Two is not in the strings list"

Answer (score 0):

You can use python `xml` module for this

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

my_list = [1,2,3,5,6]
root = ET.parse("data.xml").getroot()

for n in my_list:
    for child in root:
        if 'number' in child.attrib and child.attrib['number']==str(n):
            if 'name' in child.attrib:
                print(child.attrib['name'])
                break
    else:
        print(f"{n} is not in the XML file")
```

**Output**

```
1 is not in the XML file
Two
3 is not in the XML file
5 is not in the XML file
Six
```

Comment: thanks for the reply, can I use a list like my_list = [1,2,3,5,6] , and then have it search within the XML using the items in my_list, and print either if it is not there, or print the name? I just got an error using your code